# It is possible to hide the on screen keyboard for a mobile web page?

Tags: html, mobile, keyboard

I am designing a foreign language keyboard for a language learning site that displays the appropriate characters on the keys without the user having to install anything extra. It works just fine on a desktop or laptop with a physical keyboard, however, when it activates on a mobile device the built-in keyboard displays on the screen as well. Is there a way to focus the text cursor without bringing up the soft keyboard so that a physical keyboard can still interact with it as well as my HTML-JS keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `readonly` attribute to the input element seems to work. I tested this with IE on a WP device and Chrome on an Android device.

```
<input type="text" id="input" readonly="readonly" />
```

I have created a quick [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/n39qfaqg/)

As for the cursor, I think you could simulate it using the pipe character ("|") and some string mutation.

Comment: **Pros**: **1.** It's a solution! **2** Could probably get the `|` to be zero width and still display **3.** ... **Cons**: **1.** Would require browser/platform sniffing to work on both desktops and mobiles **2.** Would require different code for each (I don't want to prevent the keyboard input, I just don't want two on the screen at once!) **3.** Mightn't work very for non-Latin scripts such as East Asian ones that have complex relationships between Unicode code points and character glyphs **4.** Would probably require a fair bit of code to get working (not that's it going to be tiny anyway!)